# How to implement a secure personal web browser on an office PC?

Tags: security, google-chrome, user-profiles, google-chrome-extensions

My employer has a thankfully enlightened view regarding web usage during working hours and I would prefer to remain signed into my own personal web pages that I will view during quiet periods or during lunch hours.

What I would like to do is guard against either accidental or intentional access to my own personal information.

Previously, I've been running an instance of Lubuntu in a Virtual Box with a minimal amount of memory which pretty much just runs Chromium and nothing else. This virtual instance is locked via a screensaver which kicks in after 60 seconds to lock the screen.

This has been working fine but it would be nice to have a separate private browser to which only I have access. The enormous memory requirements of Visual Studio 2010 also make it necessary to claw back as much memory as possible!

I have Google Chrome installed on my office PC and I thought that I might be able to download and install Chromium as the two seem to be happy to co-exist on the same machine (I would much prefer to keep using Chrome, although I would possibly consider other browsers)

Unfortunately all of the Extensions I've found either lock single tabs at a time (not ideal) or don't seem to work at all.

Any suggestions as to an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered taking the browser off the 'machine' and leaving it on a pendrive such as [The World Browser](http://www.pendriveapps.com/the-world-browser/)? Actually, anything under the [Secure Internet Browsers](http://www.pendriveapps.com/software/internet-tools/) section of pendriveapps would do quite nicely

You can also find standard portable versions of most browsers at [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/)

Comment: Excellent, thanks, I struggled to download an English version of Google Chrome portable from the links you provided by found another version here:

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

This even has the most recent dev build.

Comment: I've had the same version sitting on my pendrive for about 3 months now... so thanks for reminding me to upgrade!

Comment: Fur the curious, I've even managed to install this to the SD card on my mobile phone and run it from there, reasoning that it's a lot less likely that I'll forget to unplug my phone rather than a memory stick from the PC each day!

Comment: For the even more curious, there is also this http://www.truecrypt.org/ which gives me a secure virtual disk drive on my machine from which to run the portable Google Chrome browser from, performance from an SD card in my phone... was... just... too.. slow.